# Dismiss all UIViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have app with 3 `UIViewContoller`

```
UIViewContollerA
UIViewContollerB
UIViewContollerC
```

`UIViewContollerA` open `UIViewContollerB` with `presentModalViewController`
`UIViewContollerB` open `UIViewContollerC` with `presentModalViewController`

And i want to have the possible that in one click on button in `UIViewContollerC` to dismiss all The UIViewController.

I try to call `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated` twice but it won't work, there is any other option to do it?
it's possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would take a look at unwind segues. They allow you to unwind to any previous segue. The answers in this question are very helpful in describing how to use them: [What are Unwind segues for and how do you use them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12561735/what-are-unwind-segues-for-and-how-to-use-them)

Also as mentioned by Michael, modals weren't designed to be placed one on top of the other. I've found they work great for forms, but not much else. I would suggest that you use a UINavigation Controller as well. This will allow you to easily navigate back to the previous controller. Then you could also add a button for an unwind segue back to the initial view controller that you want.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need some sort of chaining set of calls back up the modal stack to do this.

However, given you have a stack of view controllers, a UINavigationController might be a simpler solution to both presenting these view controllers in the first place and dismissing them down in one go.

Comment: I like the idea of a UINavigation Controller from his issue. And then he could use. An unwind segue to unwind all the way back as opposed to dismissing one at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Of course calling `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated` won't work, it's intended to be called on different view controllers. From the docs:

> > Dismisses the view controller that was presented by the **receiver**

So you'll need to set up delegation between the controllers in order to pass a request to dismiss the controller backwards to the initial controller.

Keep in mind that:

1. There's probably a better way of doing whatever it is you're trying to do. Modal controllers weren't intended to be presented on top of each other.
2. You're using deprecated methods. Use 
   `presentViewController` and `dismissViewController` instead

Answer (score 0):

you would pass a reference of `UIViewContollerB` in `UIViewContollerC`, like this

```
@property(nonatomic, assign) UIViewContollerB *refB;
```

and call `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated` in `UIViewContollerC` to dismiss it, and fire dismiss action of `UIViewContollerB` in `viewWillDisappear`

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    [self.refB dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]
}
```

Answer (score -2):

What you could try is to use `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated` with `animated:NO`. On the top most one and `animated:YES` on the controller below.

Or perhaps it workd, if you just call dismiss on the rootController?

Comment: That won't work, because he is not using a navigation controller. He is using modal views.